# How do I copy bone properties (rotation constraints) with IK from one bone to another

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I am trying to set up bone constraints on the fingers of my armature with IK. and all the information on how to copy constraints from one bone to another only apply to the constraints tab and not the bone properties tab. the long and the short is, how do I copy bone properties from one bone to another

Image below

[image: The tab with the info I am trying to copy, outlined in red]

Comment: I don't know if you can copy the whole panel but to copy each value you can use Copy to Selected, you can also select several bones, type the value and press Alt Enter

Comment: thank you moonboots that worked

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can copy the whole panel but to copy one single value you can select all your bones, shift select the one that has the value in order to make it active, then right click *Copy to Selected*. You can also select several bones, type the value and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.